# EKS/EFS - pod has unbound immediate PersistentVolumeClaims

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-eks, amazon-efs

On an EKS Kubernetes 1.21 cluster, multiple new pods fail to become deployed and remain in `pending` status.

I'm getting this event in my pods: `pod has unbound immediate PersistentVolumeClaims`

The affected pods are supposed to mount PVCs/PVs which use AWS EFS. How can I find out what's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be due to an EFS Access point limit, which is currently [set to 120](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/efs/latest/ug/limits.html).

You should be able to see this in the logs of `efs-csi-controller` for container `csi-provisioner`:

```
  ErrorCode: "AccessPointLimitExceeded",
  Message_: "You have reached the maximum number of access points (120) for your file system fs-(...). Delete an access point and add a new one."
```

And it should also be visible in the events of the affected PVC:

```
Warning  ProvisioningFailed (...) failed to provision volume with StorageClass "(...)": rpc error: code = Internal desc = Failed to create Access point in File System fs-(...) : Failed to create access point: AccessPointLimitExceeded: You have reached the maximum number of access points (120) for your file system fs-(...). Delete an access point and add a new one.
```

The solution is therefore to either delete existing PVs and their underlying EFS access points(!). Or create a new EFS drive for future PVs and PVCs.
When deleting PVs in order to delete access points, keep in mind that deleting a PV with reclaim policy `Retain` will [not trigger deletion](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/aws-efs-csi-driver/issues/517) of its underlying access point.

Comment: "...deleting a PV with reclaim policy Retain will not trigger deletion of its underlying access point." This is not obvious, therefore I decided to post this Q&A style.